# Wordpress with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress

I have Wordpress in a subfolder in my site named blog.

When I goto the url of my site /blog/ I get the error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

This use to show the default theme and an empty blog.

I think it may be a routing problem with MVC?

Does anyone know how to correctly set this up or how the routes should be configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting this in your RegisterRoutes handler in global.asax:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("blog/{*subfolder}");
```

It might also work simply with blog/*, but I am not quite sure.